# can I pass parameters to sql file with VerticaOperator in Airflow?

Tags: python, sql, airflow, vertica

I am using `VerticaOperator` in my `dag`, something like:

```
example_query = VerticaOperator(task_id="example",
                                sql='queries/example.sql',
                                vertica_conn_id="vertica", queue='default', dag=dag)
```

the query looks like that:

```
select * from table 
where id = '||&1||' -- may be where id = '{}'
```

How can I pass the parameter via the VerticaOperator?

```
example_query = VerticaOperator(task_id="example",
                                sql='queries/example.sql' 6, # 6 is the parameter for example
                                vertica_conn_id="vertica", queue='default', dag=dag)
```

If I can't, any other ideas how to use the sql file, passing the parameter and call it from the VerticaOperator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `params`. It's a reference to the user-defined params dictionary:

```
example_query = VerticaOperator(task_id="example",
                                sql='queries/example.sql',
                                params={'my_key': 6},
                                vertica_conn_id="vertica",
                                queue='default',
                                dag=dag)
```

The `example.sql` needs to be:

```
select * from table 
where id = '{{ params.my_key }}'
```